# Utility classes generated via a SASS loop not acting as expected when used with a media query

Tags: css, sass

I'm generating some margin top utility classes and have created a sass loop / function that works in px increments of 8.

Here is both:

```
@function size($num) {
    @return #{ ( $num * 8 ) }px;
}

@for $i from 1 through 14 {
    .margin-top-#{$i} {
        margin-top: size($i);
    }
    .sm\:margin-top-#{$i} {
        @media all and (max-width: $small-size) {
            margin-top: size($i);
        }
    }
}
```

When adding both of these to an element e.g.

```
<div class="list-item margin-top-6 sm:margin-top-3"></div>
```

The smaller class with the media query styles are overwritten by the initial margin-top-6 class.

How can I make this work that the sm: class will override the initial margin-top-6 class?

In my eyes this should just work because of the ordering.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path, order matters. Since the loop generates the general rule and next the media-query all the media can be overwritten by any general rule that has a superior number (that was declared after). Here is an example:

```
.margin-top-1 {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .sm\:margin-top-1 {
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
}

.margin-top-2 {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .sm\:margin-top-2 {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
}
```

> Check that `margin-top-2` will overwrite `.sm\:margin-top-1`

---

A possible solution is to break the loop in two, this way you ensure all media-queries are declared after the general rules. Here's an example:

```
$small-size: 800px;
$loops: 14;

@function size($num) {
  @return #{ ( $num * 8 ) }px;
}

@for $i from 1 through $loops {
  .margin-top-#{$i} {
    margin-top: size($i);
  }
}
@for $i from 1 through $loops {
  .sm\:margin-top-#{$i} {
    @media all and (max-width: $small-size) {
      margin-top: size($i);
    }
  }
}
```

And a [working demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b0fe14f15f1886be854f92679cc292df).